# Traer solo un elemento del Json

Tags: jquery, json

soy muy nuevo en esto y estoy haciendo un ejercicio que consiste en traer un dato de acuerdo a la la opción seleccionada, les comparto lo que tengo para ver si me pueden ayudar a saber como traigo solo un elemento y no todo el Json.

```js
function aliadoSelect(data) {

 $.each(data, function(i, item) {
  console.log (item.imgBanner);
  console.log (" ");
  console.log (item.offers.offersOne);
  console.log (item.offers.offersTwo);
  console.log (item.offers.offersThree);
  console.log (item.offers.offersFour);
  console.log (" ");
  console.log (item.howToUse);
  console.log (" ");
  console.log (item.date);
  console.log (" ");
  console.log (item.terms);

  console.log ("============");
 });
}


function aliados(dataAliados) {
 $.each(dataAliados, function(i, itemAliados) {
  $( ".aliados" ).append( "<div class='containerAliados' id="+itemAliados.idAliado+"><p>"+itemAliados.imgLogo+"</p></div>" );
 });

$(".containerAliados").click(function(event){ 
  aliadoSeleccionado = $(this).attr('id');
  console.log (aliadoSeleccionado);
  $.getJSON('aliados.json', null, function(data) {
   aliadoSelect(data);
  });
 }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() { 

 $.getJSON('aliados.json', null, function(dataAliados) {
   aliados(dataAliados);
  });


});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Somos EPM</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="aliados">
    
  </div>
  <h1 id="ver">Ver</h1>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Y este es el Json

```
[
{
    "idAliado": 0,
    "imgLogo": "App_Themes/aliados/pizza-doble-pizza/logo.png",
    "imgBanner": "App_Themes/aliados/pizza-doble-pizza/banner.jpg",
    "offers": {
        "offersOne":        "App_Themes/aliados/pizza-doble-pizza/oferta-1.jpg",
        "offersTwo":        "App_Themes/aliados/pizza-doble-pizza/oferta-2.jpg",
        "offersThree":  "App_Themes/aliados/pizza-doble-pizza/oferta-3.jpg",
        "offersFour":   "App_Themes/aliados/pizza-doble-pizza/oferta-4.jpg"
    },
    "howToUse": "Presenta tu documento de identidad o di el número a la hora de hacer tu pedido.",
    "date":         "Válido hasta el 31 de diciembre de 2019",
    "terms":        "Combo "
},
{
    "idAliado": 1,
    "imgLogo": "App_Themes/aliados/yom-yom/logo.png",
    "imgBanner": "App_Themes/aliados/yom-yom/banner.jpg",
    "offers": {
        "offersOne":        "App_Themes/aliados/yom-yom/oferta-1.jpg",
        "offersTwo":        "",
        "offersThree":  "",
        "offersFour":   ""
    },
    "howToUse": "Presenta tu documento de identidad",
    "date":         "Válido hasta el 31 de diciembre de 2019",
    "terms":        "* Aplican"
}
  ]
```

Ya consulte de varias formas pero no logro cumplir mi objetivo, que idea me pueden dar chicos?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Amigo usa la posición del indice que vas a mostar, ya que recorres con un foreach y tenes la variable "i" al momento de recorrer y hacer el .append mostra el dato así "itemAliados[i].idAliado". Exitos y avisa si funciona. Saludos..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías tener sólo una función que rescate el dato mediante el id o cualquier propiedad que quieras de la siguiente forma

```js
let data = []

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5dea9b4ebc5ffd040094f47c',
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'json',
    success: result => {
      data = result
      $.each(result, (i, itemAliados) => {
            $( ".aliados" ).append(`<div class="containerAliados" id=${itemAliados.idAliado}><p onclick="detalles(${itemAliados.idAliado})">${itemAliados.imgLogo}</p></div>`);
        });
    },
    error: (err) => console.log(`error, ${err}`)
  })
})

const detalles = id => {
  const item = data.find(i => i.idAliado === id)
  console.log(`${JSON.stringify(item)}`)
}
```

```html
<div class="aliados"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Para evitar llamar tantas veces al `JSON`, cree una variable global donde asignas el valor del resultado en la llamada.

Después simplemente llame a la *función detalles* mediante el `id` y use el método **[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find)** propio de `JavaScript` para encontrar el elemento deseado.

Cualquier duda nos comentas!

Comment: Está perfecto!, solo tengo una pregunta y es por que imprime todo con commits, incluso el texto.

Comment: A que te refieres con eso?